# how to extends mysqli "or" sqlite depending on the constractor

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, class, mysqli

I develop a class that deals with different types of databases. I want to enable the original functions by extending the original class (without adding these classes manually)

For example :

```
$db=new MyDbClass('sqlite',...);
$db->query(....);
```

The user can use the method `query()`, although `MyDbClass` doesn't have this method.
The only way to do that is to extend the proper class.

Note that i want the user to access `query()` directly from `$db` ,
not `$db->object->query();` `$db->object` is an instance of `sqlite`

Any idea?

Comment: You could route through your abstraction class with the magic [__call()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) method

Comment: This class has been already developed, it is called PDO